# remove binary files in mercurial

Tags: mercurial

I recently ran `hg add *` by accident and now binary files got added to my repo (even though I have an `.hgignore` file). How can I undo this?

I want my `.hgignore` file to catch files I don't want added

actually I found this command:

`$ hg forget "set:hgignore() and not ignored()"`

which removes the files, but then when I commit, it adds them again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked:

1. remove the files from the file system.
2. run `$ hg forget "set:hgignore() and not ignored()"`
3. commit and push

the files should get untracked and stay untracked

Comment: One (important) caveat to this method is that when a remote repo does an `hg pull` and then `hg update`, those files **will be deleted** from their filesystem. That's fine if those are build artifacts that are recreated, but not fine if those are referenced dlls or resource images.